# 3 audios at the same time with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media

I am trying to play 3 audios width Android but not at the same time, my code is the next one:

```
                for (Word w : wordsList){
                    String path = Parameters.PATH_AUDIO + "/" + w.getAudioPath();
                    Uri audioPath = Uri.parse(path);
                    MediaPlayer audio1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioPath);
                    audio1.start();
                }
```

But all audios start to play at least at the same time. I need something like `audio1.wait()` or `audio1.sleep` or someone like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using setOnCompletionListener:

```
audio1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {

      //do something when audio is finished   

}});
```

Here's an example (didn't have the chance to try it though):

Decalre these in the class level:

```
int index = 0;
MediaPlayer audio1;
```

and then:

```
try {
        audio1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(yourList.get(index)));
        audio1.start();
        index++;

        audio1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {

                if (index < yourList.size()) {
                    audio1.reset();
                    audio1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                            Uri.parse(yourList.get(index)));
                    audio1.start();
                    index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //release it
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using onCompletion but I don't know what  I must put in your comment lines, I don't have to do nothing just wait about 2 secs between each audio .

Comment: Just play the next audio when the previous one is finished.

Comment: If you just wish to wait for 2 seconds, you can use a Handler with postDelayed.

Comment: Please tell a fast example, I have my head locked!